# MInecraft not working with xbindkeys

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

### Problem

I got a new mouse. It has some extra buttons on the side, so I was thinking, how can I make this left click? Much to my dismay, mouse (a RedDragon Nirvana) has no software. My first idea was to use a program to switch the side button to the left button. After some research (about 30 minutes), I found `xbindkeys`. I had a *lot* of trouble setting this up, and after 1 hour of trial and error and some help from my friend, I managed to switch it. All is well? Not quite. This doesn't work with Minecraft because (unfortunately) Minecraft doesn't *use* X. I downloaded an autoclicker (not to be used on multiplayer) and bound it to the extra button (button 9). This does only really fast clicking, not one click, and even then, it is toggling, not oneclick.

### Summary

I would like a Minecraft mod that allows for making click macros... It should click whenever I press the desired button (button 9), and not be bannable on servers (hypixel, antiac, etc.). *Any* ideas would be much appreciated!

### EDIT

I think, if I could get Minecraft to register input from `xbindkeys` or a similar application, it would work like a charm. I'd simply make button 9 trigger `xte mouseclick 1` or `xdotool click 1`.

### EDIT EDIT

I am using Unix with a 64 bit architecture. As you can tell from the tags, I have Minecraft Java edition installed.

Comment: While you can definitely find click mods out there, click macros are basically always banned on Hypixel and similar servers for competitive/cheating reasons, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Okay... How would they ban me if I'm clicking naturally, just with a different button that can be subsituted for leftclick

Comment: It's not about what the macro does, it's the presence of the macro at all that would trip the system. I could be wrong but I believe most major servers can detect and flag mouse macros no matter their purpose.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser you can just set your minecraft keybinds for that

Comment: @Sciborg you are partially wrong, servers on minecraft, unlike other multiplayer games dont actually have any access to software on your computer, they only receive packets or information telling them what the player is doing. this is why "utility mods" are very easy to make on minecraft and very hard on games like fortnite. servers do have anticheats that do work however, they just work in a much different way. if you click really really fast, you get a ban because the server says "thats impossible for a human to do" if you killaura it detects headspin and does the same.

Comment: That's fair, I was aware that Minecraft servers don't have software access. I was just under the impression that Hypixel's Watchdog macro-detection software, for example, looked not only for fast clicking, but also for unusual input delays that could indicate mouse input is being buffered.

Comment: I believe Minecraft might have a built-in anticheat so people cannot do things like this. I figure this because the re-bound button 9 still registers as left click, just not as an attack. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong... I don't know a lot about how Minecraft was implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use an autoclick program and set it up to activate and stop when you press the 9 key... https://www.opautoclicker.com/        this is an easy to use autoclicker, which I use (not in pvp servers...). You can also set it up to click how many times you want, how fast you want, left click/right click, single or double click...
Really useful

Comment: Sorry... I cannot seem to find a Linux download. I am currently looking for a UNIX/Linux port. Please link any Linux downloads/ports down below.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the side mouse button to the attack/destroy button in minecraft

Comment: Yes, but then, I wouldn't be able to left-click to attack, unless I rebound left click as attack...

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in the title/post previously, I believe I have fixed it now.

Answer (score -1):

ON Windows, you can get [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and make a simple script like this:

```
XButton1::LButton
```

If that doesn't work switch out `XButton1` for `XButton2`. This should do what you want without disabling left click.

Comment: AutoHotKey is not available on Unix-based OSes.

Comment: @RayWu according to wikipedia windows makes up 88% of OSes used globally. If they don't specify its pretty safe to assume windows

Comment: The question states that they are using a Unix-like OS (xbindkeys, X, xdotool, xte)

Comment: Sorry. editing now

Comment: @Penguin @RayWu I am having some trouble installing AutoHotKey on Linux... I tried to do the command `xbuild AutoHotKey.sln`, but despite the message "Build succeeded", I cannot seem to find the AutoHotKey installation (i.e. `AutoHotKey` fails, and I can't find any binary files...)

Comment: @stackoverflowuser I didn’t realise this was for linux earlier so I edited a bit ago to specify in Windows. I’m guessing it’s having issues because AHK offers GUIs which are built for the Win32 API

Comment: @Penguin gotcha... Is there something using a cross-platform windowing API like Raylib?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser maybe, I dont know anything about that tbh and I don't wanna give misinformation. I think this only applies to windows.

Comment: Okay... I'll just leave this post up for any Windows users that find it helpful.