# How do I bind both right-click and keypress to action in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I would like to be able to use either right-click or V in order to place blocks and blockhit in Minecraft. I am using Minecraft 1.8.9 on Linux (Ubuntu).

I would like to bind my right-click to <kbd>V</kbd>. Then in Minecraft, I'll bind <kbd>V</kbd> to place block, so I can blockhit using <kbd>V</kbd> and place block using right-click.

I tried using xbindkeys. It seems work outside of Minecraft, but when I open Minecraft, and join a world, it does not work.

How do I double keybind in Minecraft?

Comment: Your question could be a little clearer. Is this not possible with the controls menu?

Comment: @MrParrot No i want to double keybind, i want to bind my right click to v then in minecraft i bind v to place block so i can shield using v and place block using right click is that clear?

Comment: minecraft not allowing me to do this so i want a software that allow me to bind right click to v

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for a software is considered a recommendation, hence off-topic here.

Comment: Voting to leave open. The question isn't a request for subjective recommendation advice. ["These \[types of\] questions *describe a problem* and then *request a specific solution to that problem*"](//meta.arqade.com/a/5548). ["**Judge questions by *the problem being posed*** instead of the presupposed answer"](//meta.arqade.com/a/6830). ["Closing the question because a \[software\] request is present doesn't make sense."](//meta.arqade.com/a/8168). ["Give us the actual problem… and we'll solve that, and if the solution involves \[software\], so be it"](//meta.arqade.com/a/11579/).

Comment: are you running in full-screen or windowed mode? it's possible that in fullscreen mode Minecraft communicates with the mouse directly, but in windowed mode it would go through X.

Comment: Also you can't use a different key for shield and place block. Whichever key you choose for one is the same as for the other.

Comment: @Esther i can double keybinding as i said i bind my right click key to v so i can either place block using v or using right click.

Comment: the problem is i already did the double keybinding thing using xbindkeys but when i open minecraft and try it out it not working.

Answer (score 1):

if you bind right-key to 'V', then Minecraft will see *all* right-clicks as the letter V (unless you *also* bind 'V' to right-click, in which case it will only get right-click input if you press 'V'). If you then bind 'V' to "place block", then you will *both* place blocks *and* shield with right-click (which Minecraft thinks is 'V').

There is no way to use a different key for shield and place block, since Minecraft can only bind them to the same key. Changing "place block" also changes the key you shield with, unless you get a mod (in theory; in practice I don't know of any mod that does this, but that would be the only way).

Comment: but i can use xbindkeys to bind right click to v and (in minecraft)bind my right click key to v so i can press right click to place block or hit block and i can also do it that using v

Comment: why xbindkeys not working

Comment: already made a topic about it [https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/398253/why-is-xbindkeys-not-working-in-minecraft?noredirect=1#comment559526_398253]

Comment: @Ok. did you read the answer? What do you expect Minecraft to do? What *actually happens* when you press 'V' and right-click in Minecraft?

Comment: you want to right-click using *either* 'V' *or* right-click? Is that it?

Comment: yes that what meant sorry if the topic i made is confusing

Comment: @Ok. the *other question* you started is most likely going to be closed as a duplicate of this one (since it asks basically the same thing), but I can edit your question to clarify so people understand what you're asking

Comment: the double keybinding thing is working outside minecraft but when i open minecraft and try it out it not working i use fullscreen if that matter.

Comment: @Ok. try in windowed mode. It is possible that Minecraft bypasses some OS graphics/input processing when in fullscreen, but in windowed mode it will use the OS processing (including xbindkeys)

Comment: ok lemme try that real quick

Comment: seems not working even though i try it on window mode

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380539/minecraft-not-working-with-xbindkeys looks like Minecraft doesn't use X at all, and therefore bypasses xbindkeys entirely.

Comment: oh well is there any similar program that can do the same as xbindkeys did but bypasses minecraft,