# Why is XbindKeys not working in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I use XbindKeys to bind my right click to <kbd>v</kbd> but when I open Minecraft and try it out, it's not working.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or is it simply not possible to use XbindKeys in Minecraft?

Comment: minecraft version that im using is 1.8.9 i want to bind right click to v so i can place block and block hit separately this make block hit timing much easier ykyk

Comment: You already posted [a very similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/398239/how-do-i-double-keybind-in-minecraft-on-linux), please don't do that. Edit the old question instead if you need to add something.

Comment: run in windowed mode, see if that changes anything. Also how exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per pinckerman's comment.

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate. Please edit your original question if you want to add more details.

Comment: ye just close it i already solve it